# FreeBSD copy directories with skip

Tags: freebsd

I need to copy folders by this command:

```
cp -R /usr/www/data/www.domaun.com/WWW/ /usr/www/data/new.domain.com/
```

But skip directories:

```
audio
b
f
img
tmp
```

and also skip files larger than 3 MB.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), e.g.

```
rsync -a --max-size=3M \
    /usr/www/data/www.domain.com/WWW/ /usr/www/data/new.domain.com/ \
    --exclude audio/ --exclude b/ --exclude f/ --exclude img/ --exclude tmp/
```